# Wikitude Titanium module sample project runtime error

Tags: android, titanium-modules, wikitude

I'm trying to run the sample project of the Wikitude module for Appcelerator Titanium.
I've carefully followed [all steps on the docs](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/appcelerator#_48_INSTANCE_mwSOv1YHsJ4g_=setupguidetitaniumandroid.html#setup-guide-titanium-module-android), but I consistently get the following error during runtime:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [12112,12112] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,12112] - In ui/windows/ARchitectWindow.js:26,42
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,12113] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Wikitudeand> has no method 'isDeviceSupported'
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,12113] - Source:         var isDeviceSupported = wikitude.isDeviceSupported(_this.augmentedReal
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ui/windows/ARchitectWindow.js:26: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Wikitudeand> has no method 'isDeviceSupported'
```

This happen every time I try to launch any of the examples contained in the app.
I can't figure out how to fix that. I'm trying to launch the application on a Samsung Galaxy S2, which should be compatible.

I imported the module from the Appcelerator marketplace at first, but also tried to manually put the ZIP in the root folder of the project with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last update of the module (3.3.1) resolved the issue.